# perl regex - to extract function definition arguments

Tags: regex, perl

```
eErrorT ChainCtrlExit (ChainCtrlT * pChainCtrl)
ChanT* ChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan (ChainCtrlT * pChainCtrl, 
char * name 
)
eErrorT ChainCtrlInit (ChainCtrlT * pChainCtrl, 
char * name, 
int instance, 
void * pOwner 
)

int SymContDecNamesCount = (sizeof(SymContDecNames)/sizeof(SymContDecNames[0]))
char* SymContEncNames[]
int SymContEncNamesCount = (sizeof(SymContEncNames)/sizeof(SymContEncNames[0]))

I want to extarct only function arguments ...that is
```

OUTPUT I NEED extract only function definition arguments in one line

```
 ChainCtrlT * pChainCtrl
 ChainCtrlT * pChainCtrl, char * name 
 ChainCtrlT * pChainCtrl, char * name, int instance, void * pOwner
```

MY CODE

```
open(FILE, "< functions2.txt") or die $!;
open(FILE1, "> functions3.txt") or die $!;            

my @Array1=<FILE>;
foreach my $text (@Array1){
   $text =~ /\((.+)\)/;
   print FILE1 $text;
 }
```

But it is extracting everything into new file. Basically dulication of file content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
open(my $FILE, "<", "functions2.txt") or die $!;
open(my $FILE1, ">", "functions3.txt") or die $!;            


my $s = do { local $/; <$FILE>; };
while ($s =~ /^ \S+ \s+ \S+ \s* \( (.+?) \) /xsmg) {
  my $arg = $1;
  $arg =~ tr|\r\n||d;
  print $FILE1 "$arg\n";
}
```

Comment: works fine. As i am new to perl, it will be great if you could share some links to understand how to solve such issue rather than just copying blindly your code.

Comment: @Ad-vic check perldoc documentation => [link1](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)
[link2](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Global-matching)
[link3](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles)